$(k a_k^2)_k \in l^1$ does not imply that $a_k \in l^1$
Suppose we have a sequence $(a_k)_k$ such that $(ka_k^2)_k \in l^1$ and $(a_k)_k \in l^2$. I guess that $(a_k)_k$ does not have to be in $l^1$, since the Hölder-inequality does not hold. However, I found it very difficult to come up with an counter example. Looking at something along the lines of $a_k = \frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ clearly does not work and multiplying with $log(k)$ in the denominator or similar approaches have also not worked.
I would appreciate some help.

Well known example: $a_k=\frac 1 {k \ln k}$.

Try $a_1 = a_2 = 0$ and
$$
a_n := \frac{1}{ n \log (n) }
$$
for $n \ge 3$. Since
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n a_n^2
=
\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \log^2(n)}
\le 
\int_{2}^{+ \infty} \frac{dx}{ x \log^2(x) }
=
\int_{\log(2)}^{+ \infty} \frac{d u}{ u^2 }
< + \infty,
$$
we know that $\{ n a_n^2 \}_n \in \ell^1$. But
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n
\ge 
\int_{3}^{+ \infty} \frac{dx}{ x \log(x) }
=
\int_{\log(3)}^{+ \infty} \frac{du}{u}
=
+ \infty,
$$
we know that $\{ a_n \}_n \notin \ell^1$.

In general the mapping $\ell^2\ni \{a_k\}\to \{b_ka_k\}\in \ell^2$ is bounded iff the sequence $\{b_k\}$ is bounded. Equivalently this problem is equivalent to whether
$$\sum a_k^2<\infty \implies \sum b_k^2a_k^2<\infty$$ In your case $b_k=k^{1/2},$ which is clearly unobunded.
In case $\{b_k\}$ is unbounded there is a sequence $\{a_k\}\in \ell^2$ such that $\{b_ka_k\}\notin \ell^2.$ Indeed, choose an increasing sequence of indices $n_k,$ such that $|b_{n_k}|\ge 2^k.$ Then define $a_{n_k}=2^{-k}$ and $a_j=0$ if $j\neq n_k$ for all $k.$ Then $\sum a_n^2<\infty$ but the series $\sum b_j^2a_j^2$ is divergent, as $b_{n_k}^2a_{n_k}^2\ge 4^k\cdot 4^{-k}=1.$
In your case let $a_{4^k}=2^{-k}$ and $a_j=0$ if $j\neq 4^k$ for any $k.$ Then $4^ka_{4^k}^2=1,$ hence the series $\sum ka_k^2$ is divergent, while the series $\sum a_k^2$ is convergent.
